# How can I get previews of open windows using GTK2?

Tags: c, gtk, gtk2

I am thinking about maybe creating a tasklist widget using GTK2. This widget should show previews of all open windows. It does not matter whether the previews update in real time or not.

I already have some knowledge of GTK2 and libwnck, and I have created my own widgets before.

How do I get previews of open windows using GTK2? What general methods are available for doing this kind of thing, and what might I need to research? Please note that I do not want to use anything that depends on OpenGL.

Comment: This is not a coding service. What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Olaf I think I may have tried something using GDK (I can't remember exactly what I did), but it segfaulted. I think I have seen an example where they used Xlib to do this, as well. What are my general options if I want to get previews of windows?

Comment: For starter, you can start learning to program using gtk2 in general. For process data you should have a look at procfs (supposing you are using Linux). That's all I can give here and most likely you will get for this off-topic question. A more specific question once you have something done might get better results. - sorry.

Comment: @Olaf I already have some knowledge of GTK2 and libwnck, and I have created my own widgets as well. So, is Xlib the best thing to research? Do you know if there are ways of doing this without using Xlib?

Comment: Does wnck not provide the functionality you need? I have a feeling what you want to do is outside the scope of GDK.

Comment: @andlabs AFAIK wnck does not provide any method for getting a preview/image of a window.

Comment: @andlabs Do you know of any toolkits that might provide this functionality?

Comment: @Olaf I have tried using gdk_pixbuf_get_from_drawable, and this seems to work, but it could be a bit slow and rather CPU-inefficient. Is there a more CPU-efficient way of doing this?